# javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:

Tags: websphere, javax

My system get hung for the moment and it get restart automatically . please help what need to be change or update in websphere

```
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:465)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.internal_addObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1494)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:974)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:928)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.PlatformMBeanServer.registerMBean(PlatformMBeanServer.java:484)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.TCHierarchyDynamicMBean.addLoggerMBean(TCHierarchyDynamicMBean.java:109)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.TCHierarchyDynamicMBean.addLoggerMBean(TCHierarchyDynamicMBean.java:84)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.jmx.PlmSimpleMBeanFactory.addNewLogger(PlmSimpleMBeanFactory.java:377)
    at com.teamcenter.mld.logging.Log.<init>(Log.java:837)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.util.Log.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.util.LogFactory.getLog(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.util.AbstractMonitoring.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.WebtierMonitoring.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.serveraccessor.ServerAccessor.initializeMonitoring(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.serveraccessor.ServerAccessor.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.serveraccessor.ServerAccessor.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:201)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.resourceadapter.spi.impl.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getServerAccessor(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.resourceadapter.spi.impl.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2086)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1761)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:2636)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:701)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.resourceadapter.spi.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.ejb.GatewayBean.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.ejb.EJSRemoteStatelessGateway_6578a643.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.jeti.ejb._Gateway_Stub.authenticate(_Gateway_Stub.java:552)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.gateway.login.TcLoginManager.login(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.wae.internal.ctrl.context.RequestDispatcher.isLoggedIn(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.wae.internal.ctrl.context.RequestDispatcher.processRequestContainer(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.wae.internal.ctrl.context.ControllerContextImpl.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.wae.internal.ctrl.injector.RequestInjectorImpl.processRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.wae.internal.ctrl.Controller.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.wae.internal.ctrl.Controller.service(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.teamcenter.presentation.gateway.filters.CompressionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.teamcenter.soa.ptier.ResponseTimeFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
 ##
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at that stack, a resource adapter with package com.teamcenter.jeti.resourceadapter is trying to create a managed connection which is driving com.teamcenter.jeti.WebtierMonitoring to attempt to register an mbean with the server.  You can uninstall the RA if you're not using it, or see if it's possible to turn off the mbean registration.

Comment: We are not getting this error on daily bases . and i am not much aware about the web sphere .  So i did not understand the meaning of RA can you please let me know where i have make the changes to check the impact of this change .

Comment: and from where we can turn off the mbean registration

Comment: Poking around a bit, it appears this may be part of something called Teamcenter Web tier application which is deployed to this WAS instance. The exception causing the stack trace you posted is clipped from the top, please update the trace with that info.  Also, you should examine the WAS logs in <WAS_HOME>/profiles/<profile_name>/logs/server1 for additional details.

Comment: 6/20/17 3:13:12:952 EDT] 00000013 SystemOut     O ERROR - Could not add loggerMBean for [com.teamcenter.mld.healthmonitoring.MetricManager].
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: log4j:cell=tcuawsp2Node01Cell,loggers=all,node=tcuawsp2Node01,process=server1
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:465)

Comment: yes this is the issue with the Teamcenter . the error log which i have provided is of WAS SystemOut.log file . this error came only when system gone into hung state . i have also check the RA in WAS but there is no values . SO if you need any other infomation then please let me know